# testing an actual returning value on javascript using jest

Tags: jestjs

I have the following js function:

```
const modelUtils = {

modelingObj(obj, stringVal = ‘RE’) {
let newObj;
//my logic for setting value of newObj
return newObj;
};

export default modelUtils;
```

I want to test and see that based on a specific params I get a particular result, the issue is I’m always returning back an empty object.

Test.js

```
import modelUtils from '../modelUtils';

jest.unmock('../modelUtils');

describe(' testing modelUtils', () => {
  let test;

  const mockData = {
    myProperty: [],
  };
  describe('testing modelingObj function', () => {
    it('For my first test’, () => {

        test = modelUtils.mockData, ‘TR’);
      expect(test).toEqual({ myProperty: [] });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I think your *modelUtils* is missing some relevant code, and it has some flaws (you are using the literal *Let* with uppercase *L* and are missing a *{*). Furthermore, you are testing a *modelingObjmockTableCol* method that does not appear in your *modelUtils* module.

Could you edit your question and correct/provide the relevant code?

Comment: yes will update, those are missing due to copy pasting

Comment: Your code has a syntax error. Can't run